# routing table Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, routes, routetable

I have strange problem.
I'm working with Windows 7.

I add line to routing table:

> route -p add 192.111.111.111(fake of course) mask 255.255.255.255 192.111.197.254 metric 10

Now, when I ping 192.111.111.111 -everything is OK.
But, when I restart my computer -magic gonna happens.

This line is still visible in route table but I cant connect to this address.
I have to write this line again, then prompt line answers:

> The route addition failed: The object already exists.

And after that I can connect to this address.
It happens every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -p switch makes the new route persistent. As a result, the route remains in the routing table so you should choose CHANGE instead of ADD commmand.